# ONLY style the input of form

Tags: css, forms, input

So, I have a form.

I want to add a `padding` to the form fields. So, when people start typing, the text will appear with a nice gap between the sentences and the left border of the field...

I can use `padding-left`, but then the who field jumps to the left (but it does work for the text).

I am looking for CSS code that allows me to style the `input` text on its own.

I tried this code, but that won't work either.

```
input[type=text] {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

[image]

EDIT: I posted a picture what happens when using padding-left on input[type=text]. It does work but on the right you can see what happens with the field. The field gets wider..

Comment: This code is fine. Maybe you have other overriding settings or something. Consider providing us with a http://jsfiddle.net reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `padding` gets added to the rendered `width` of a field.

Use the `box-sizing` property to solve it.

```
input[type=text] {
    padding-left: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This worked pretty well! Needed to adjust some other stuff to, but you gave the best answer!